# How to combine functions in a class in Python?

Tags: python, static-classes

I have a code like this. In my original code I would like to call two or more methods when a button is clicked.

```
class MyApp(object):

    @staticmethod
    def combine_funcs(*funcs):
        def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for f in funcs:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
        return combined_func

    def __init__(self):
        MyApp.combine_funcs(self.my_first_func, self.my_second_func)

    def my_first_func(self):
        print("First")

    def my_second_func(self):
        print("Second")


my_app = MyApp()
```

When I run this nothing is printed. Why?

Comment: You're just combining the functions, you're not *calling* your newly combined functions function.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need parenthesis. However when I want to call them when a button is pressed `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(MyApp.combine_funcs(self.converter(), self.showMessage()))` is it the same? They are immediately called, not waiting for a mouse click?

Comment: `combine_funcs(self.converter(), ...)` is not the same as `combine_funcs(self.my_first_func, ...)`, now is it?

Comment: Ok, it seems I have more issues with my code. `()` executing a function. This is why my __init__ didn't do anything. I understand that now. The second problem is when I remove `()` in `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(MyApp.combine_funcs(self.converter, self.showMessage))` I get an error `converter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Converter function takes only `self` argument. What 2 arguments am I sending?

Comment: When it is finally called, it is being passed arguments…

Comment: Ok, but which 2 arguments am I giving? I get `TypeError: converter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: When `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect` (or such) finally does call the function, it passes one argument (in addition to `self`)…

Answer (score 2):

A method is not much more than a member of a class that happens to be a function. The magic is just that when it is called on an object (`a.func(x...)`) the object is automatically prepended in the argument list resulting in the actual call `A.func(a, x...)`.

What you want can be obtained that way:

```
class MyApp(object):
    # prepend with _ to "hide" the symbol
    def _combine_funcs(*funcs):      
        def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for f in funcs:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
        return combined_func

    def my_first_func(self):
        print("First")

    def my_second_func(self):
        print("Second")

    # actually declares combined as a method of MyClass
    combined = _combine_funcs(my_first_func, my_second_func)
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = MyApp()
>>> a.combined()
First
Second
```

---

But a much cleaner way would be to use a decorator for that in Python 3:

```
import inspect

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def outer(f):
        def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):    # combine a bunch of functions
            for f in funcs:
                x = f(*args, *kwargs)
            return x                           # returns return value of last one
        combined_func.__doc__ = f.__doc__      # copy docstring and signature
        combined_func.__signature__ = inspect.signature(f)
        return combined_func
    return outer

class MyApp(object):

    def my_first_func(self):
        print("First")

    def my_second_func(self):
        print("Second")

    @combine_funcs(my_first_func, my_second_func)
    def combined(self):
        """Combined function"""
        pass
```

The decorator will replace the body but will keep the docstring and the signature of the original function (in Python 3). You can then use it normally:

```
>>> a = MyApp()
>>> a.combined()
First
Second
>>> help(a.combined)
Help on method combined_func in module __main__:

combined_func() method of __main__.MyApp instance
    Combined function

>>> help(MyApp.combined)
Help on function combined_func in module __main__:

combined_func(self)
    Combined function
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `combine_funcs`, but the function within that, `combined_func`, is not being called.

Is there a reason not to simplify to:

```
class MyApp(object):

    @staticmethod
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in args:
            f()

    def __init__(self):
        MyApp.combined_func(self.my_first_func, self.my_second_func)

    def my_first_func(self):
        print("First")

    def my_second_func(self):
        print("Second")

my_app = MyApp()
```